# Localhost after Apache update

Tags: apache, apache2, localhost, virtualhost

My problem is:

Some days ago I had updated my Apache, from 2.2 to 2.4. I noticed a strange behaviour of server. I have some virtual hosts and they work correctly. But, when I try to open **localhost**, I see one of my virtual hosts, not content "index.php" from document root.

Part of my /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   crm
127.0.0.1   cp
```

So, when I'm typing **localhost** and press "Enter", I see **crm** or **cp** host.

My **crm vhost**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName crm

    DocumentRoot /var/www/odcrm
    <Directory /var/www/odcrm>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You have to post your configuration of the virtual hosts. We cannot _guess_ that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, cause is it - my inattention. I forget to enable default vHost - 000-default.conf. It is first in vHosts list and **localhost** shows right content now.